# Proving inequalities using field axioms

Tags: inequality

I know that the following is an ordered field: $$(F,\leq) $$ I have to prove that:
$$\forall x\in F (x>0)  \implies x>x/2 > 0$$
as well as:
$$\forall x\in F (x>0)  \implies x^{-1}>0$$
by only using field and ordering axioms. I think I might have found how to prove the second by doing the following: I suppose x > 0 and know  that $x*x^{-1} =1$. Therefore $x*x^{-1} >0$, because $1>0$. Then there is 3 possibilities: If $x^{-1} = 0$ then $x^{-1} * x = 0$ which is wrong. If $x^{-1} < 0 $ then $x * x^{-1}$ cant be greater than 0, but I know that it equals 1. Therefore $x^{-1} > 0$.

Could anyone help me out with the first one?

Comment: Hint: $x = x/2 + x/2$, so if $x > 0$, can you have $x/2=0$ or $x/2 < 0$?

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the multiplication law:

If $c > 0$, then $a < b$ iff $ac < bc$.